# MYSQL UPDATE field with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, special-characters, sql-like

I want to remove special characters from a field so I am trying to update several records in a table by using:

```
UPDATE tEmployees 
   SET last_name = REPLACE(last_name,"%Ã¡Ã±%","añ") 
 WHERE last_name LIKE '%Ã¡Ã±%'
```

however, I got the message say 0 row(s) affected so it didn't work.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tEmployees WHERE last_name LIKE '%Ã¡Ã±%'
```

and got rows affected, so I am confused. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have wildcard characters when calling `REPLACE()`. It replaces literal strings, not `LIKE` patterns. So take out `%` in the `REPLACE()` argument.

```
UPDATE tEmployees 
   SET last_name = REPLACE(last_name,"Ã¡Ã±","añ") 
 WHERE last_name LIKE '%Ã¡Ã±%'
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mcdsPVZWHDEnufi5kzoUsW/0)